# Xamarin iOS - Dismiss dialog notification

Tags: ios, xamarin

I use UIImagePickerController to open image from photo library.

I can register handlers for both accept and cancel events

```
imagePicker.Canceled += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
//handle cancelling... 
}
imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia += (sender, args) =>
{
 //handle loading... 
}
```

These two handlers get called when user picks a photo, or clicks the Cancel button.

But, when user closes the dialog by **swipe down gesture**, I do not get my Cancel event handler called, what I believe should happen (as the user indeed has canceled the load operation).

So, what am I missing ?
Is there any other event that I can subscribe to, to get notified when user closes dialog by swiping it down the screen?

Comment: Is there any logs about this issue?

Comment: No logs are available. No handlers are called, which I register (I was expecting the canceled event handler to get called. Nothing happens. When I swipe down, I can see the page from where I initiated the Image Picker...

Comment: Could you please post a basic demo to github or onedrive so that we can test on our side?